# Argument type 'lambda expression' is not assignable to parameter type 'System.Action'

Tags: c#, mvvm, lambda, mvvmcross

This issue drives me insane since past couple hours.

I have 2 versions of the same property I wrote:

```
public IMvxCommand ButtonClickedCommand
{
    get
    {
        return new MvxCommand(() =>
            {
                Mvx.Resolve<IMvxWebBrowserTask>().ShowWebPage("http://google.com");
            });
    }
}
```

And

```
public IMvxCommand ButtonClickedCommand
{
    get
    {
        return new MvxCommand((Action) (() =>
            {
                Mvx.Resolve<IMvxWebBrowserTask>().ShowWebPage("http://google.com");
            }));
    }
}
```

Both methods are correct, both are being run when button is clicked and they do what they have to do. But the first one shows me this:

[image]

The second:

[image]

If there is no solution for it, and it's some kind of a bug I will drop it, but the other project I'm working on, is using the v3 library also, and there is no such issue.

Lucas

//Edit

I'd like to add more detail to the issue, so that maybe it will help find the reason of the problem.

There is generaly no problem with lambda expressions if I write them for the methods I create myself. For example:

```
public void fun()
{
    fun2(() =>
             {
                 GetType();
             });
}

public void fun2(Action action)
{
}
```

This snippet above is using a lambda expression for the required Action parameter, so the situation very similar to the one from the first snippet, and yet there is no problem with that. The problem is, if I pass the lambda expression to the constructor of MvxCommand object that I will not explicitly cast to Action.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt this has anything to do with `mvvmcross` or `mvvm`

A quick search for this error message suggests this is more likely to be down to tooling - especially r# - eg see hits like:

- http://devnet.jetbrains.com/thread/292248
- http://caliburn.codeplex.com/discussions/212685
- http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-178647?projectKey=RSRP

If you are running any extensions like r# and you remove or disable them, then this may remove the warning.

---

If disabling them helps, then I would recommend asking the extension vendor(s) for support.

If disabling them does not help, then I would recommend investigating the differences between the two projects where the problem does/doesn't occur - that will hopefully yield the answer.

Comment: Suspending the R# did make the warning/error go away. It is strange that the method I wrote did not show the warning though. I will mark this message as the answer for now. I will try to investigate the problem and if I encounter the root of the cause I will post back. Thanks Stuart.